# Flex how to avoid using errno

Tags: windows-ce, bison, lex

I am using Flex&Bison in winCE 6.0.

There are some problem in errno.h.

In my SDK the errno.h is:

```
#ifndef _INC_ERRNO
#define _INC_ERRNO

#include <crtdefs.h>

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Error Codes */
```

But the SDK of VC which also used in Flex is:

```
#ifndef _INC_ERRNO
#define _INC_ERRNO

#include <crtdefs.h>

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* declare reference to errno */

#ifndef _CRT_ERRNO_DEFINED
#define _CRT_ERRNO_DEFINED
_CRTIMP extern int * __cdecl _errno(void);
#define errno   (*_errno())

errno_t __cdecl _set_errno(__in int _Value);
errno_t __cdecl _get_errno(__out int * _Value);
#endif

/* Error Codes */
```

So,is it possible to avoid using `errno` in Flex?

Add some option? or privode myself header file instead of errno.h?

Comment: @rici can you help me?

Comment: Did you get some error? Becouse, as for me, looks fine. Both .h declare same interface and `#ifndef _INC_ERRNO` will prevent use them both in same time.

Comment: uh..I find out it with `extern int errno` in lexer.l and in one .cpp file with `int errno`...it   looks fine.